# Source that Power generators on Shabbos override Shlom Bayt (in Israel)

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, electricity

Power generators are very popular with Haredim in Israel that traditionally don't rely on [Isral Electric Company](https://www.iec.co.il)'s electricity on Shabbos.

On Rosh Hashana, the power generator of a famous Yeshiva in Bnei Brak went up in flames and R' Chaim Kanevsky was asked to acknowledge switching to IEC. That spawned (again) a discussion on this topic and R' Chaim was remembered for his "**prohibition of visiting parents that use IEC on SHabbos at expense of Shlom Bayt**".

I'm looking for the source of that statement and its roots.

Comment: Interesting news bit. Can you add a link to an article that explains this scenario? Besides personal curiosity, I think, in terms of this question, it may be better to get the full picture of the situation. A somewhat similar situation occurs among some people in U.S. - Many families won't use hot plates on Shabbat b/c of its dangers and several tragic incidents in the past approx. 5 years of house fires caused by these plates. Some families encounter *Shalom Bayit* issues (mine, included) by those who won't eat a Shabbat lunch that doesn't include hot food. (I forgo S.B. for safety.)

Comment: @DanF What scenario you refer to?

Comment: About not using *chashmal* on Shabbat. In particular, how is using a generator "solving the problem". Isn't there an equivalent *melacha* by doing this? I'm trying to understand the "logic" of not using IEC. Never mind. I found a related MY question on this topic.

Comment: @DanF In the times of the speeding technological progress, I realized that many Haredim feel obligated to stringent their positions to compensate for the easiness of keeping Shabbos. Switching to generators and the accompanying suffering make their lives more meaningful. The background is easy - many Jews are employed on Shabbos to maintain (not to produce) the electricity in Israel, which makes it not/less Kosher. Putting the lights on a generator is easy, but AC or plates...